# WordPress Settings hack: Membership check box gets checked

Tags: wordpress, settings, membership

I'm working on an old WordPress site and cleaning out all the old dusty plugins and whatnot(Updated or **removed** any unneeded plugins/themes). Nothing unusual. I added security to the login and other precautions, but about a month ago I received a notification to my admin email that someone created an account and changed their password.

When I investigated, the new user had admin rights and some random username. I immediately deleted the user and soon discovered that the Membership checkbox in Settings was toggled to "Anyone can Register". The default role set to Admin. I had never seen anything like this before, but I couldn't recall if I checked this setting when I started working on the site.

So I unchecked the box, set the default role to subscriber. I chalked it up to me missing a step and moved on. Fast forward to now and over the weekend it happened again. A new user, changed password, and there low and behold the Membership checkbox was checked. I deleted the new account as before.

Although this time the default user was still set to subscriber. So that didn't change.

I tried to Google this, but I don't get anything other than the steps I've taken.

A couple of quick details; the site is backed up, and I am the only admin user. WordPress 5.8.2. PHP 7.4, all plugin updates done automatically.

If you have an idea of what's happening please let me know.

Comment: Difficult to say anything without any code. Maybe try to recreate what's happening. Create a dummy account and look at each steps. If the process is clean then you have a security failure, probably coming from the plugin itself or the payment platform.

Comment: Regarding the "default role set to admin" you might want to implement an IP address whitelist for admin account just as a temporary measure.

Comment: @amarinediary That's a great idea, I had IP whitelisting  on my list, but I haven't tried it yet. The code is standard WordPress v. 5.8.2

Comment: How about your plugins, are they still updated (maintained), have you tried looking for similar behaviour out there related to your plugins and not WordPress itself. What do you mean by "old WordPress site" if you're using `5.8.2` ?